Cross table sorting in mongodb
How do I sort a response from a table according to the other table's key?
For example:
I have a table named user data. The contents of the table is:
{ _id:objectId, name:string, age:number}
Now I have another table named employee salary data. The contents of the table is:
{ _id:objectId userId:objectId //ref to user totalSalary:number}
What I want here is that when I fetch a data from the employee salary, I want to sort the result by the user's name (which is in the user table) or totalSalary (whichever the user inputs on the order that user mentioned)
I am using mongoose 8.4.5 if there is any query that I can use in mongoose, please let me know. If you prefer aggregate pipeline please give me a code example as I am new to aggregation pipelines.

use aggregation with lookup and then unwind the result to sort by your desired field
here is a live example
and below is how you can call it in mongoose
Salary.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "userId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "users"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "users.name": 1
    }
  }
]).exec((err, users) => {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(users);
});

make sure to replace the schema names with yours

tried this, but I had some issues : 1) I got the data of users as an empty array in the output
2) I used $match initially but the entire data returned is an empty array
For example:
`return await userModel
.find({ isDeleted: false, ...where })  ---this worked (mongoose)
But return await userModel.aggregate([
{ $match: { isDeleted: false, ...where } }, ---this didn't work`

uodate: I found the issue in the $match. There was a$in used in it. So, what should I do to remove the $in?
